# Typescript can't force generic to be passed

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to have this utility which has a generic object Type and takes a key belonging to that type and the property associated with it like this:

```js
export type StateBuilder = <StateSchema, Keys extends keyof StateSchema>(
  key: Keys,
  data: StateSchema[Keys]
) => StateSchema;
```

The issue is, I can't seem to pass the `StateSchema` Type. It always gives back the error

`Type 'StateBuilder' is not generic. ts(2315)`

### Details

This is to be used inside a reducer function returned by a store generator.
The main idea is to supply this function type to the reducer function using the store generator

```
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode, createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export type ReducerAction<Type = string> = {
  type: Type;
};
export type ReducerActionWithPayload<Type = string, Payload = unknown> = {
  type: Type;
  payload: Payload;
};

export type StateBuilder = <StateSchema, Keys extends keyof StateSchema>(
  key: Keys,
  data: StateSchema[Keys]
) => StateSchema;

export const generateStore = <Actions extends ReducerAction | ReducerActionWithPayload, State>(
  defaultValue: State,
  reducer: <Key extends keyof State, Property extends State[Key]>(
    state: State,
    action: Actions,
    stateBuilder: (key: Key, data: Property) => State
  ) => State
): {
  Provider: (props: { children: ReactNode }) => ReactElement;
  dispatcher: (action: Actions) => void;
  useStore: () => State;
} => {
  const store = createContext(defaultValue);
  const { Provider } = store;

  let dispatch: React.Dispatch<Actions>;

  const ProviderElm = (props: { children: ReactNode }): ReactElement => {
    const { children } = props;
    const [state, dispatcher] = useReducer(
      (state, action) =>
        reducer(state, action, (key, data) => ({
          ...state,
          [key]: data,
        })),
      defaultValue
    );
    dispatch = dispatcher;
    return <Provider value={state}>{children}</Provider>;
  };

  return {
    Provider: ProviderElm,
    dispatcher: (action: Actions) => dispatch && dispatch(action),
    useStore: () => useContext(store),
  };
};
```

### Example

```
const DefaultStore = {
  token: null as Nullable<string>,
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

type ActionTypes = |
  ReducerAction<'AUTHENTICATION'> | 
  ReducerActionWithPayload<'SET_TOKEN', {token: string}>;

const { Provider: FormProvider, dispatcher: formDispatcher, useStore: useFormStore } = generateStore<
  ActionTypes,
  typeof DefaultStore
>(DefaultStore, (state = DefaultStore, action: ActionTypes, stateBuilder) => {
  switch (action?.type) {
    case 'AUTHENTICATION': {
      return stateBuilder('isAuthenticated', true);
    }
    
    case 'SET_TOKEN': {
      return stateBuilder('token', action.payload);
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
});

export { FormProvider, formDispatcher, useFormStore };
```

Currently returning the error

```
Argument of type '"isAuthenticated"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Key'.
  '"isAuthenticated"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Key', but 'Key' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '"isAuthenticated" | "token"'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
export type StateBuilder<StateSchema, Keys extends keyof StateSchema> = (
  key: Keys,
  data: StateSchema[Keys]
) => StateSchema;
```

Here, the type `StateBuilder<T, K>` itself is generic and you have to specify both its type arguments to use it. The way you were declaring it, `StateBuilder` is an alias to a generic function type whose type variables are meant to always be inferred and cannot be specified from the `StateBuilder` name itself.

A more useful answer can be given if you present an example of how you want to use the type and what do you expect from it. Maybe do you want to specify only the object type and let TS to infer the key type?

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood what you are trying to do but it looks like you are trying to make a function to take a state and update the values on it. In that case, you still need to provide your original or starting state. Something like this might be what you are looking for.

You can just create a generic function and not have to worry about creating a generic type and then using that to create a function. You can use this utility function in any store.

```
const stateBuilder = <TState, TKey extends keyof TState>(state: TState, key: TKey, value: TState[TKey]) => ({ ...state, [key]: value });

let defaultValue = {
    foo: "hello",
    bar: 10
}

defaultValue = stateBuilder(defaultValue, "bar", 20);

console.log(defaultValue);
```

UPDATE

This should be what you are looking for. The main part is the `StateBuilder` type. It needed generics on both sides. One side to tell you what State it's working with and on the other side for the key/value since those are based on what you pass to the function.

```
import React, { ReactElement, ReactNode, createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

export type ReducerAction<Type = string> = {
    type: Type;
};

export type ReducerActionWithPayload<Type = string, Payload = unknown> = {
    type: Type;
    payload: Payload;
};

type StateBuilder<State> = <Key extends keyof State, Value extends State[Key]>(key: Key, value: Value) => State

export const generateStore = <Actions extends ReducerAction | ReducerActionWithPayload, State>(
    defaultValue: State,
    reducer: <Key extends keyof State, Value extends State[Key]>(
        state: State,
        action: Actions,
        stateBuilder: StateBuilder<State>
    ) => State
): {
    Provider: (props: { children: ReactNode }) => ReactElement;
    dispatcher: (action: Actions) => void;
    useStore: () => State;
} => {
    const store = createContext(defaultValue);
    const { Provider } = store;

    let dispatch: React.Dispatch<Actions>;

    const ProviderElm = (props: { children: ReactNode }): ReactElement => {
        const { children } = props;
        const [state, dispatcher] = useReducer(
            (state: State, action: Actions) =>
                reducer(state, action, (key, data) => ({
                    ...state,
                    [key]: data,
                })),
            defaultValue
        );
        dispatch = dispatcher;
        return <Provider value={state}>{children}</Provider>;
    };

    return {
        Provider: ProviderElm,
        dispatcher: (action: Actions) => dispatch && dispatch(action),
        useStore: () => useContext(store),
    };
};

export type DefaultStore = {
    token?: string;
    isAuthenticated?: boolean;
}

const defaultStore: DefaultStore = {
    token: "",
    isAuthenticated: false,
};

type ActionTypes = |
    ReducerAction<'AUTHENTICATION'> |
    ReducerActionWithPayload<'SET_TOKEN', { token: string }>;

const { Provider: FormProvider, dispatcher: formDispatcher, useStore: useFormStore } = generateStore<
    ActionTypes,
    DefaultStore
>(defaultStore, (state = defaultStore, action: ActionTypes, stateBuilder) => {
    switch (action?.type) {
        case 'AUTHENTICATION': {
            return stateBuilder('isAuthenticated', true); //typechecked
        }

        case 'SET_TOKEN': {
            return stateBuilder('token', action.payload.token); //typechecked
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
});

export { FormProvider, formDispatcher, useFormStore };
```

Comment: But In my case, I don't need to pass in the state as it already has access to the State Schema in the upper Scope.
And also, when using state builder I want to have intelisense on the key and value based on what I pass. For example, if I call `stateBuilder('bar', 'not a number')` it should tell me of the mismatch

Comment: Okay, It looks like you are basically doing what I'm doing when passing the function in the higher scope, so the state is already there. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I didn't understand you're question. I'm generating the stateBuilder when calling the useReducer React function.
Also thank you for the help :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I made some changes to your example to make the type check work on your actions.

Comment: Sorry, not sure why it doesn't work. My first function type checks the property type just fine and the only thing different is the state parameter.

Comment: Alright, it took a minute, but I think I got it this time.